# Deselect radio buttons active element on loading a file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

I have created a group of radio buttons to look like a progress bar for a website. On a load of a file from the local system, data segments will be loaded into each radio button or the progress bar. I can click on each radio button to see the data loaded into each segment. I have css styles working on the radio buttons to show that radio buttons have been clicked by changing colors of the button. I want to refresh the radio buttons onclick colors when I load other files from the local machine. In other words, I want to refresh button colors on loading a different file from the local system. I have my code here which is being selected or at least I want to have a clear button which can deselect all the active elements. The code I worked on does not seem to be working.

```
 <div class="w3-display-container col-md-12 col-sm-10 col-xs-8" style="position:relative;top:1px;bottom:0;">
  <!--<div class="container">-->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" data-toggle="buttons">
      <label class="btn btn-default">
                                            <input type="radio" name="options" id="option29" autocomplete="off" onchange="dataSegment(28)">
                                        </label>
      <label class="btn btn-default">
                                            <input type="radio" name="options" id="option30" autocomplete="off" onchange="dataSegment(29)">
                                        </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="clearAllRadios()">clear me</button>

  <style>
.btn-default {
  color: #D8D8D8;
  background-color: #D8D8D8;
  border-color: #D8D8D8;
}

.btn-default:hover {
  background-color: #5F5A66;
}

.btn-default.active {
  background-color: #4A90E2;
  color: #4A90E2;
  background-color: #4A90E2;
}

.btn-default.color {
  background-color: #4A90E2;
}

.btn-default.focus {
  background-color: #1E3B5D !important;
}

input[type=radio] {
  margin-top: -6px;
}
  </style>

  <script>
$('.btn.btn-default').on("click", function() {
  $(this).addClass('color');
});

function clearAllRadios() {
  var radList = document.getElementsByName('radioList');
  radList.value = false
}
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code will be works for you,

```js
$('.btn.btn-default').on("click",function(){ 
       $(this).addClass('color');                        
});

$('#Button1').on('click',function() {
       alert('click');
       $('input:radio[name=options]').each(function () {                                      
                $(this).prop('checked', false);
                $(this).removeClass('color'); 
                $(this).parent().removeClass('color'); 
       });                  
});
```

```css
 .btn-default{color: #D8D8D8;background-color: #D8D8D8;border-color: #D8D8D8;}
.btn-default:hover{background-color: #5F5A66;}
.btn-default.active{background-color:#4A90E2;color:#4A90E2;background-color:#4A90E2; }
.btn-default.color {background-color: #4A90E2;}
.btn-default.focus{background-color:#1E3B5D !important;}
input[type=radio]{margin-top:-6px;}
```

```html
  
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <div class="w3-display-container col-md-12 col-sm-10 col-xs-8" style="position:relative;top:1px;bottom:0;"><!--<div class="container">-->
             <div class="row">
                   <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" data-toggle="buttons">
                        <label class="btn btn-default">
                                <input type="radio" name="options" id="option29" autocomplete="off" onchange="dataSegment(28)">
                         </label>
                         <label class="btn btn-default">
                                <input type="radio" name="options" id="option30" autocomplete="off" onchange="dataSegment(29)">
                         </label>
                    </div>        
              </div>
        <button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="clearAllRadios()">clear me</button>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the solution.adding $(this).parent().removeClass('active'); piece of code along with your solution worked miracles.

Comment: If it is working for you. Please accept it as your answer

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

`var radList = document.getElementsByName('radioList');`

getElementsByName returns an HTMLCollection, not a single element. If you want to make sure all radio buttons with `radioList` name are unchecked, you would do:

```
document.querySelectorAll('input[name="radioList"]').forEach(btn => {
  btn.checked = false
});
```

The getElementsBy* methods return HTMLCollections, which can be difficult to work with. querySelectorAll is a bit nicer to interact with; it returns a static NodeList - unlike an HTMLCollection, it can be iterated over directly, it won't change while it's being iterated over, and it's much more flexible.

Comment: there's a missing ' by the way